# OpenWindowStation error 183 /ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS/

Tags: c#, winapi, winlogon

I'm writing a program with remote administration functionality and I stuck with some problems. The main issue is, that every calling of 'OpenWindowStation' results in 'error 183' and a Null-pointer.

This code runs as a service on a LocalSystem account. I also tried to allow a desktop interaction, but all of these were in vain.

I've reviewed a couple of similar questions here, but no one of their decisions helped me.

```
    namespace sasserv
    {
public class sasserv : ServiceBase
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenWindowStation( string name, bool fInherit, uint needAccess );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr CloseWindowStation( IntPtr hWinSta );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenDesktop( string name, Int32 flags, bool fInherit, long param );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr CloseDesktop( IntPtr hDesktop );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage( IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, IntPtr lParam );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool SetThreadDesktop( IntPtr hDesktop );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool SetProcessWindowStation( IntPtr hWinSta );

    public const string MyServiceName = "sasserv";

    public sasserv()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start this service.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        RunWinlogon();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop this service.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }       

    protected void OutputLastError(string funcName) {
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if ( err > 0 )
            Out(funcName, "ERR:"+err);
    }

    private void RunWinlogon()
    {
        int WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS = 0x37F;
        long DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004L;
        long DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002L;
        long DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040L;
        long DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008L;
        long DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020L;
        long DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010L;
        long DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001L;
        long DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100L;
        long DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080L;
        int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
        uint WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
        short MOD_ALT = 0x0001;
        short MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
        short VK_DELETE = 0x2E;
        uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;

        uint WLX_WM_SAS = 0x0659;
        uint WLX_SAS_TYPE_CTRL_ALT_DEL = 0x0001;

        uint GENERIC_READ  = 0x80000000;
        uint GENERIC_WRITE  = 0x40000000;
        uint  GENERIC_EXECUTE  = 0x20000000;
        uint GENERIC_ALL  = 0x10000000;
        uint  GENERIC_RIGHTS_CHK  = 0xF0000000;

        Out("OpenWindowStation", "Running2");
        var hWinSta = OpenWindowStation( "WinSta0", false,  MAXIMUM_ALLOWED );
        if (  hWinSta == IntPtr.Zero ) {
            Out("OpenWindowStation", "hWinSta=ZERO");
            return;
        }
        OutputLastError("OpenWindowStation");


        Out("SetProcessWindowStation", "Running");
        if ( !SetProcessWindowStation( hWinSta ) ) {
            Out("SetProcessWindowStation", "FALSE");
            return;
        }

        OutputLastError("SetProcessWindowStation");

        Out("OpenDesktop", "Running");
        var hDesk = OpenDesktop( "Winlogon", 0, false, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);

        OutputLastError("OpenDesktop");

        if ( hDesk == IntPtr.Zero ) {
            Out("OpenDesktop", "HDESK=ZERO");
            return;
        }


        if ( !SetThreadDesktop(hDesk) ) {
            Out("SetThreadDesktop", "FALSE");
            return;
        }

        OutputLastError("SetThreadDesktop");

        Out("PostMessage", "Running...");
        var postSucc = PostMessage( new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST),
                                   WLX_WM_SAS,
                                   WLX_SAS_TYPE_CTRL_ALT_DEL,
                                   IntPtr.Zero);

        OutputLastError("PostMessage");         

        CloseDesktop( hDesk );
        CloseWindowStation( hWinSta );          
    }

    static IntPtr MakeLongPtr( short wLow, short wHigh ) {          
        return new IntPtr( (UInt32)(wLow | ( (UInt32)wHigh << 16 )));
    }

    static void Out( string func, string info ) {
        NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        logger.Info( "FUNC: "+func+" . INFO: "+info );
    }
}
}
```

Here is a log of execution:

Here is a log of execution: 
12.07.2016 10:29:47.3526|sasserv|FUNC: OpenWindowStation . INFO: Running2
12.07.2016 10:29:47.3646|sasserv|FUNC: SetProcessWindowStation . INFO: Running
12.07.2016 10:29:47.3646|sasserv|FUNC: SetProcessWindowStation . INFO: ERR:183
12.07.2016 10:29:47.3746|sasserv|FUNC: OpenDesktop . INFO: Running
12.07.2016 10:29:47.3746|sasserv|FUNC: OpenDesktop . INFO: ERR:183
12.07.2016 10:29:47.4025|sasserv|FUNC: SetThreadDesktop . INFO: ERR:183
12.07.2016 10:29:47.4065|sasserv|FUNC: PostMessage . INFO: Running...
12.07.2016 10:29:47.4065|sasserv|FUNC: PostMessage . INFO: ERR:87

Comment: Your error reporting is broken. You cannot call `GetLastError` in that way because the .net runtime calls Win32 API functions. Use `SetLastError = true` in your `DllImport` attributes and then call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`.

Comment: Thanks, David! I provided your correction, but the main problem still remains!

Comment: So, this issue still has no decision. So, I decided to use _ExitWindowsEx_ function (temporary) for changing a user (by logging off).

Comment: Of course,this is also quite weird decision, but that's enough for the first version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the DLL imports as `SetLastError=true` and then use [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) instead of `GetLastError()` directly.  From the documentation:

> `GetLastWin32Error` exposes the Win32 `GetLastError` function from Kernel32.DLL. **This method exists because it is not safe to make a direct platform invoke call to `GetLastError` to obtain this information**. If you want to access this error code, you must call `GetLastWin32Error` instead of writing your own platform invoke definition for `GetLastError` and calling it. The common language runtime can make internal calls to APIs that overwrite the `GetLastError` maintained by the operating system.
>
> You can use this method to obtain error codes only if you apply the System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute to the method signature and set the SetLastError field to true. The process for this varies depending upon the source language used: C# and C++ are false by default, but the Declare statement in Visual Basic is true.

For example:

```
namespace sasserv
{
    public class sasserv : ServiceBase
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenWindowStation( string name, bool fInherit, uint needAccess );

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern IntPtr CloseWindowStation( IntPtr hWinSta );

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenDesktop( string name, Int32 flags, bool fInherit, long param );

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern IntPtr CloseDesktop( IntPtr hDesktop );

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern bool PostMessage( IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, IntPtr lParam );

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern bool SetThreadDesktop( IntPtr hDesktop );

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
        static extern bool SetProcessWindowStation( IntPtr hWinSta );

        public const string MyServiceName = "sasserv";

        public sasserv()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // TODO: Add cleanup code here (if required)
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start this service.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            RunWinlogon();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stop this service.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            // TODO: Add tear-down code here (if required) to stop your service.
        }


        protected void OutputLastError(string funcName) {
            int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Out(funcName, "ERR:"+err);
        }

        private void RunWinlogon()
        {
            int err = 9999;
            int WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS = 0x37F;
            long DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004L;
            long DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002L;
            long DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040L;
            long DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008L;
            long DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020L;
            long DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010L;
            long DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001L;
            long DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100L;
            long DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080L;
            int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
            uint WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
            short MOD_ALT = 0x0001;
            short MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
            short VK_DELETE = 0x2E;
            uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;

            uint WLX_WM_SAS = 0x0659;
            uint WLX_SAS_TYPE_CTRL_ALT_DEL = 0x0001;

            uint GENERIC_READ  = 0x80000000;
            uint GENERIC_WRITE  = 0x40000000;
            uint GENERIC_EXECUTE  = 0x20000000;
            uint GENERIC_ALL  = 0x10000000;
            uint GENERIC_RIGHTS_CHK  = 0xF0000000;

            Out("OpenWindowStation", "Running1");
            var hWinSta = OpenWindowStation( "WinSta0", false,  MAXIMUM_ALLOWED );
            if ( hWinSta == IntPtr.Zero ) {
                OutputLastError("OpenWindowStation");
                return;
            }

            Out("SetProcessWindowStation", "Running");
            if ( !SetProcessWindowStation( hWinSta ) ) {
                OutputLastError("SetProcessWindowStation");
                CloseWindowStation( hWinSta );          
                return;
            }

            Out("OpenDesktop", "Running");
            var hDesk = OpenDesktop( "Winlogon", 0, false, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);

            if ( hDesk == IntPtr.Zero ) {
                OutputLastError("OpenDesktop");
                CloseWindowStation( hWinSta );          
                return;
            }

            if ( !SetThreadDesktop(hDesk) ) {
                OutputLastError("SetThreadDesktop");
                CloseDesktop( hDesk );
                CloseWindowStation( hWinSta );          
                return;
            }

            Out("PostMessage", "Running...");
            if ( !PostMessage( new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST),
                                       WLX_WM_SAS,
                                       WLX_SAS_TYPE_CTRL_ALT_DEL,
                                       IntPtr.Zero) ) {
                OutputLastError("PostMessage");
            }

            CloseDesktop( hDesk );
            CloseWindowStation( hWinSta );          
        }

        static IntPtr MakeLongPtr( short wLow, short wHigh ) {

            return new IntPtr( (UInt32)(wLow | ( (UInt32)wHigh << 16 )));
        }

        static void Out( string func, string info ) {
            NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            logger.Info( "FUNC: "+func+" . "+info );
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, another way to issue a Ctrl-Alt-Del sequence is to use the [`SendSAS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761.aspx) function instead of broadcasting a `WLX_WM_SAS` window message.

Comment: Thank you, Remy! I know about SendSAS, but here we've several problems: 1. We need to email to MS and wait for their response 2. We need to run this code on WinXP (32bit).

Comment: @IgorEvdokimov you do not need to email MS, in fact the SAS email is deprecated and not likely to respond. You just need the `sas.dll` redistributable from the Win7 SDK.

Comment: thanks a lot! I think, I'll use it in non-WinXP environment!